# Create directory by mkdir

Tags: linux, perl, directory, mkdir

I want to create a folder named by the user name in /tmp/vnc/, I can create that folder in command line with `perl -e 'mkdir("$ENV{USER}")'`, but for the following code cannot work.

```
chdir ("/tmp/vnc") or die -1;
mkdir ("$ENV{USER}", 0777) or die -1;
```

If I use `mkdir -p /tmp/vnc/$ENV{USER}` in command line to make folder, nothing happens and no error reports.

Comment: `... or die "Error in mkdir: $!\n"` might tell you more. `$!` gives you the error code from the previously failed operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It said "Error in mkdir: File exists", but the directory named by user name does not exist.

Comment: @thinkman Maybe there is a file (or a fifo, or a socket) with the same name. You cannot have a directory and a file with the same name.

Comment: ... or the user account which runs this script does not have permissions to create a file or directory inside /tmp/vnc ...!!

Please check

ls -ld /tmp/vnc

to see the permissions of that directory

Comment: @Tilo: if that user didn't have permission the error probably would have read "permission denied" instead of "file exists".

Comment: PHP 8.x: I got two errors with @GraemePerrow's 10 year old comment. *(1)* `die` needs brackets *(2)* `$!` parsing error. A working solution is `mkdir($path) or die("Error in mkdir: ".var_export(error_get_last(), true)."\n");`. (Probably for PHP 7.x as well?)

Comment: @s3c My comment (and the original question) is perl, not php

Comment: My bad. Didn't even notice. Well, here's a PHP solution if anyone's interested. Intriguingly similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check special variable $! for text error message
2. Please check that variable $ENV{USER} doesn't contain extra quotes. I had similar problem in Windows OS for Activer Perl. My problem was in extra quotes

Comment: Thank you for answering the question I asked 3 years ago. :-)

Answer (score 6):

It works for me.
Maybe the `/tmp/vnc` directory does not exist, and the `chdir` fails.
Or maybe the `$USER` environment variable is not defined, because you are running it from a init.d script, for example... 
Or maybe you do not have write permissions in the `/tmp/vnc` directory. Have you tried executing `mkdir /tmp/vnc/$USER` from the shell?

Impossible to know more without details.

Comment: I am sure /tmp/vnc has been already existed. I can do this in command line by perl -e 'mkdir("$ENV{USER}")'

Comment: mkdir /tmp/vnc/$USER cannot work, since vnc is a directory, $USER is a subdirectory, mkdir does not support create a directory under a parent dir.

Comment: @thinkman Of course it does. As long as the parent directory already exists.

Comment: @teambob The weird thing is that the command "mkdir -p /tmp/vnc/test"  does not work, but when I go to /tmp/vnc then "mkdir test", it does work.

Comment: Now, that doesn't make any sense! And what is the error of `mkdir -p /tmp/vnc/test`?

Comment: @teambob If there is no error report, how do you know that it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is resetting your environment when you are running the script?  Can you print the contents of `$ENV{USER}` and make sure it contains what you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

if $ENV{USR} is an absolute path (with the leading slash), then the chdir is useless since you are not using a relative path

Comment: $ENV{USER} is only a user name, I just want to create a folder named by username under /tmp/vnc/